# Change Displayed URL in address bar

Tags: url, web, url-rewriting

I have a project. I am running wildfly server. There is a signing in form through which the users sign in to the service. When they sign in `http://localhost:8080/PMS/web` this is the url on the address bar where `web` is the name of my servlet. How can i change it to something like `http://localhost:8080/PMS/user/home` so that it gives better readability ?
I managed to change the url using `history.pushState()`. Is this a good way ?

Comment: We'd need more information for giving a proper answer. What kind of web server are you running? Apache, Nginx, Tomcat, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Tucky to rewrite URL at server side. It works very well for my purpose. Here is the link. 
http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, yes, you can modify the URL with [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) but that's not the intended use for such feature. Ideally, you should use server-side URL rewriting for such purposes.

Comment: does server side url rewriting change address displayed in address bar ?